# python: active_directory module: checking for username

Tags: python, active-directory

Have an odd issue while using the active_directory module, which is amazing BTW...  awesome wrapper.

Anyhow, I have a need to make sure that a username is unique... heres my function:

```
import active_directory

def creative_name(fname, lname, n=1):
    uname = fname[:n] + lname
    x = active_directory.find_user(uname)
    if x: creative_name(fname, lname, n+1)
    else: return uname

if __name__=='__main__':
    print creative_name("Sarah", "Smith")
```

it keeps coming up with None...  I would expect it to return uname... or

```
fname[:n+1] + lname
```

its strange because if I run the function like this:

```
def creative_name(fname, lname, n=1):
    uname = fname[:n] + lname
    x = active_directory.find_user(uname)
    if x: creative_name(fname, lname, n+1)
    else: print uname

>>>
SaSmith
>>>
```

SaSmith is returned... why won't it return the value?!?! print uname works but return uname returns None!

Please help!

Thanks all,

Randy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't returning `SaSmith` because the recursive part wasn't being returned, so if `x` was true the function returned `None`. Adding in one `return` should fix:

```
def creative_name(fname, lname, n=1):
    if n > len(fname): return None
    uname = fname[:n] + lname
    x = active_directory.find_user(uname)
    if x: return creative_name(fname, lname, n+1)
    else: return uname
```

.

Note: the first line prevents an infinite loop if `active_directory.find_user(fname[:n]_lname)` is True for every `n`.

*I agree with @Randall that using a `for` loop is probably more readable, it returns `None` in the above case.*

Answer (score 0):

oh man...  much easier.

```
import active_directory

def creative_name(fname, lname):
    for i in range(1,len(fname)):
        uname = fname[:i] + lname
        x = active_directory.find_user(uname)
        if not x: return uname

if __name__=='__main__':
    print creative_name("Sarah", "Smith")
```